Book about a pilot who crashes into a tower where each level opens into a different world
I am trying to find a name of a science fiction book I read in the past. It's at least 22 years old, so it was released earlier than 2002. More likely it was released earlier than year 2000.
The plot starts with the pilot (protagonist, don't remember their gender) crashing on his aircraft (I believe it was a helicopter, but I may be wrong) into a tower of sorts. The pilot explores the tower, and finds that different levels of the tower open up into different worlds (realms, dimensions?).
The pilot also encounters a copy of his crashed craft (he/she knows that because he/she took something from the original craft, like a tool or an emergency ration, and its still present in the copy).
The pilot also encounters some sentient beings (spiders I believe, but I may be wrong) (I also believe they were robotic in nature) that he/she learns to communicate with telepathically (I believe he/she tells them to bring food and they bring something.
I know it's not much to go off, but hopefully someone read it. I tried asking AI chats but all I got was complete hallucinations, unfortunately.

Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Do you happen to remember any details of the cover?  (Art, or even just the overall colour?)  Where was the pilot when they crashed?  On Earth or another planet?  Over a city, or was the tower in the middle of wilderness?

You could improve this Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

There are similarities to Phillip Jose Farmer's Dungeon series. I don't think the protag was a pilot though, nor do I remember the duplicate aircraft.

@DavidW no, it was generic sci fi cover, the book was released in Russia (translated I believe) and that was the way it was typically done - theyd choose a generic sci fi cover which sometimes barely matched the plot
